# Can't Read File (Python)

Tags: python, file

I have an issue.
I am trying to create a file, ask for 2 inputs, convert that into a dictionary, add it into the file, then display it.
Here is my code:

```
addressBook = open("address.txt","w+")
addresses = {}
newName = input("Enter contact's name: ")
newAddress = input("Enter contact's address: ")
addresses[newName] = newAddress
addressBook.write(str(addresses))
print(addressBook.read())
print(addresses)
addressBook.close()
```

but for some reason, printing only prints the dictionary 'addresses' and not the file's contents (which should also be 'addresses').
It should return the dictionary twice. Once is printing it directly, and once is printing it using the file.
However, it only prints it once. The file doesn't print, only the `print(dictionary)` itself.
Moving `addressBook.close()` to the front before printing doesn't help either.
Thanks!

Comment: And another issue is that after writing, you need to set the filepointer of the file to the beginning in order to print whatever was saved.  As is, once it ```addressBook.write(str(addresses))```,  the file pointer is at the end of the file.  ```addressBook.seek(0)``` should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>It is because the file is opened in write mode and not in read mode.</strike> Thank you @kabanus for pointing it out!

My corrected answer is at the bottom after the **edit**:

This works on Python 3 on my machine as expected, meaning it prints the dictionary twice.

```
addressBook = open("address.txt","w+")
addresses = {}
newName = input("Enter contact's name: ")
newAddress = input("Enter contact's address: ")
addresses[newName] = newAddress
addressBook.write(str(addresses))
addressBook.close()

with open('address.txt', 'r') as addressBook:
    print(addressBook.read())

print(addresses)
```

If you want to know more about that, here is the corresponding documentation on `open`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

**EDIT:**

You write some characters to your file, meaning that the file pointer points to the character after your string. When you want to call `.read()` it returns you the text after the file pointer which is empty. This can be solved by just using `.seek(0)` to reset the file pointer back to the beginning.

```py
addressBook = open("address.txt","w+")
addresses = {}
newName = input("Enter contact's name: ")
newAddress = input("Enter contact's address: ")
addresses[newName] = newAddress
addressBook.write(str(addresses))
addressBook.seek(0)
print(addressBook.read())
print(addresses)
addressBook.close()
```

Comment: You can also read with w+ as OP has. Your first sentence is wrong, and there is no need to open twice.

Comment: Thank you! Just realized that this can be realized with `addressBook.seek(0)` because the file pointer points n characters further. That is why it does not show the content of the file after writing and then reading.

Comment: I removed the DV since you now you have the correct solution. I would suggest removing the first part which seems unnecessary,

Comment: In general - when you amend your posts there is no need to have an "edit" section - just remove the parts you want to remove, and add the parts you want added, for the most accurate and concise answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following instead of `str(addresses)`:

```
addressBook.write(addresses.__str__())
```

Or you can go even fancier and use the `json` module:

```
import json
...
addressBook.write(json.dumps(addresses))
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked! unfortunately, I can't give multiple 'solved' check marks out...

Answer (score 0):

You can let the json library to organize your file for you. And if you use the r+ then you can write and read from the same file.

If you use with open, then the file will close it self when you end the indent, and for comunicating the json to the file, you will use load for reading and dump for writing :)

```
import json

with open("address.json","r") as addressBook:
    try:
        addresses = json.load(addressBook)
    except:
        addresses = {}
    finally:
        print(addresses)

with open("address.json","r+") as addressBook:
    newName             = input("Enter contact's name: ")
    newAddress          = input("Enter contact's address: ")
    addresses[newName]  = newAddress
    addressBook.write(json.dumps(addresses))
    addresses = json.loads(addressBook.read())
    print(addresses)
```

Hope it helps :) Good luck!

Comment: You can also read and write with `w+` as OP has. That's not the difference.

Comment: Thanks! this worked too! I can't give multiple 'solved' check marks out, but if I could, this with the other 2 would definitely get them!

Comment: Thats ok, im just here to help ;-)